# How to see the data types of all columns in SQL Sever Management System

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I could not find answer to this question, despite it being very basic. How do I know whats the data type of all columns in SQL Server management System?

```
Col1   Col2   Col3 and so on
```

I wish to know the datatypes of each column in say `Table1` where `Table1` is the name of my table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of options to see the data types of columns of the desired table -

**Option 1**

`sp_help <tableName>` e.g. sp_help Table1

**Option 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
```

**Option 3**

1. Expand the Tables
2. Expand the desired table
3. Expand the columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many several way to do this, one of them is to use `schema` :

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' or
      COLUMN_Name = 'col1';
```

Comment: Pls add how we can find datatype of a single column in a table too

Comment: . . . You can find the data type under data_type column. This is really basic thing that you need to find yourself.